# How can I set string Setting.Default = Application.StartupPath so when it is open for the first time?

Tags: c#

UPDATE: I know the title is messed up. But I cant fix this problem any help would be greatly appreciated.
I have string that is used as a directory for files in my program to be written and read. When the person installs the program I need it to make this string set to Application.StartupPath but not forever.

To Clarify:

[Make path = Application.StartupPath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZNWi.png)

Comment: "When the person installs the program I need it to make this string set to Application.StartupPath but not forever." means ? you want that string to be set on first run after install only? after that.. if person start-stop-start application.. it should not be set ?

Comment: After that I have method that allows them to change it.

Comment: I didn't downvote because of the title. I downvoted because after reading your question 3 times I'm still not sure what you're trying to do.

Comment: So, ultimatily setting it with Application.Startup for the first run only ?? right?? you can use registry for that

Comment: Please see the picture.

Comment: pseudo-code: `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(settingValue) { settingValue = Application.StartupPath; }`?

Comment: OK thank you im stupid lol.

Comment: If that works, I recommend adding an answer for it (and then I'll upvote it). It makes your question useful for other people that have the same question. I would add one but I don't use settings since I do backend API dev, so I'm not familiar with it.